# Why is the output 0.000000?

Tags: c

Can someone explain why this outputs 0.000000 for both of the variables "area" and "peri"?

```
int main()
{

    double length, width, peri = (length*2) + (width*2), area = length*width;

    printf("Enter the length of the rectangle in centimeters: ");
    scanf("%lf", &length);
    printf("\nEnter the width of the rectangle in centimeters: ");
    scanf("%lf", &width);

    printf("The perimeter of the rectangle is %lf cm.\nThe area of the rectangle is %lf cm.", circ, area);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're computing _before_ entering the values! C is not a dynamic equation solver, it's a procedural language.

Comment: You're actually lucky that you're getting zero!  You could've gotten flying monkeys!

Comment: @abelenky Or nasal demons.

Comment: The behaviour of your program is undefined.   The `peri = (length*2)+(width *2)` sets `peri` based on the CURRENT - at that point - values of `length` and `width`.   It doesn't set up some magic so, whenever `length` and `width` receive values, `peri` does too.   Instead, `length` and `width` are uninitialised before the values are read, so accessing their values to initialise `peri` and `width` gives undefined behaviour.  Printing zero is one possible result.  Formatting your hard drive is another possible result.

Comment: Note: "The area of the rectangle is %lf cm." should be something like "The area of the rectangle is %lf cm2`." as the units of area in this case are "cm2".

Comment: Why the downvotes? You can get C++ to behave like this using *actors*. And Excel works like this too, in a way. For me at least, that legitimises the question. This question is asked well with compilable code.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: Funny that. I recommend starting with C to learn the basics of programming.

Comment: @Bathsheba Python would've caught this error. It doesn't let you do stuff that would be UB in C.

Comment: @Peter Don't answer in comments. Answer in answers.

Answer (score 5):

Aton, it seems if you are assigning an expression to a variable and think the expression will be evaluated every time a variable of that expression changes.

That is so in excel, but not in C.

In C you specify calculations that will be executed at the moment the program flow/sequence passes through the code. So in C you would write:

```
int main()
{
        double length, width, peri, area;

    printf("Enter the length of the rectangle in centimeters: ");
    scanf("%lf", &length);
    printf("\nEnter the width of the rectangle in centimeters: ");
    scanf("%lf", &width);
    peri = (length*2) + (width*2);  // <== perform calculations only now
    area = length*width;
    printf("The perimeter of the rectangle is %lf cm.\nThe area of the rectangle is %lf cm.", peri, area);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I favor answers like this because not only does it explain what was wrong with the code and how to correct it, but it recognizes and addresses a mistaken idea that the asker may have had. Fixing a mistaken idea so the asker can correctly reason on their own is more valuable than merely fixing mistaken code.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is well identified by others: C  is procedural and attempts to computes `peri = (length*2) + (width*2)` at that time with the values of `length, width`.

```
// OP's code with its problem
double length, width, peri = (length*2) + (width*2), area = length*width;
```

This is further complicated in that `peri = (length*2) + (width*2)` is using uninitialized variables at that time which is *undefined behavior* (UB).  The output of "0.000000"  is likely due to `length` and/or `width` being zero at the time of computation, yet as UB, anything may have happened  like a code crash, other output or who-knows-what.

---

An alternative solution: establish the relationship of `peri = (length*2) + (width*2)` by creating a function

```
double peri(double length, double width) {
  return (length*2) + (width*2);
}

int main(void) {
  double length, width;
  printf("Enter the length of the rectangle in centimeters: ");
  scanf("%lf", &length);
  printf("\nEnter the width of the rectangle in centimeters: ");
  scanf("%lf", &width);

  printf("The perimeter of the rectangle is %lf cm.\n, peri(length, width));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not guaranteed to output anything at all. You are calculating your result before you receive the input. C stores numbers in variables; it doesn't use Symbolic Algebra.

In order to fix your code, simply perform the calculation after you take input.

Answer (score -1):

**Easy Fix:**

```
int main()
{

double length, width, peri, area;

////////////////////////////////////
// Gather your inputs
////////////////////////////////////
printf("Enter the length of the rectangle in centimeters: ");
scanf("%lf", &length);
printf("\nEnter the width of the rectangle in centimeters: ");
scanf("%lf", &width);

////////////////////////////////////
// Now that you have a length and width, do your calculations
////////////////////////////////////
peri = (length*2) + (width*2);
area = length*width;

printf("The perimeter of the rectangle is %lf cm.
\nThe area of the rectangle is %lf cm.", circ, area);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: My comments in the code clearly explain what and why.

Comment: But not how to solve the problem in future. It doesn't explain what the problem is unless you already know what the problem is. "Now that you have a length and width" isn't very useful if the OP thought that they already had the length and width anyway.